# How To Put Multiple User Loads Like ( 100 , 200 Users ) on a Premade Selenium Script In Python Webdriver In Odoo?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, odoo

I have made an automated script in Python using Selenium WebDriver.  It is used to test one menu process in [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/).  Now, how can I put user load or a network load like 100, 200 users' load on that script?

Comment: you can't really do that with selenium webdriver.

Comment: so what I have to do without a payment option & with the use of selenium @CoreyGoldberg

Comment: provide me an easy way to do this , I have a readymade python selenium webdriver script & I want to use it for user's load

Comment: I just edited your question so it makes more sense, and then answered it below.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer what I *think* you are asking...

In a nutshell, you are using the wrong tool for the job.  Selenium WebDriver runs an actual browser, and you can't run many instances of that in parallel for any sort of reliable load generation or testing.

So for generating any substantial workload, your WebDriver script is not useful.  Most people do performance and load testing with a different set of tools, and use Selenium for doing acceptance testing.

If you are doing load testing, you might want to check out something like [Locust](http://locust.io/), which is designed for generating concurrent load by simulating HTTP requests.

Also, your question is confusing.  You state that you want to put user load on 
a menu process?  That is pretty vague, but generally a menu is implemented on the client side... so it wouldn't give you many scalability concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your concern , but in short I want to tell like I have made one script in python for odoo app , so will I able to integrate that script with other tool for user load testing because , for odoo app very few information is available & specially for python not as much info is available like JAVA , So it is more confusing

Comment: the fact that you are using Odoo is nearly irrelevant... It's just a web application like any other.  So please read my answer again... the answer is basically saying **you can't do that**, and then gives an alternative tool to try.

Comment: all right , understood , thanks for your support brother

Comment: Is Funkload plugin for python will be supported or not , it is given by someone in stackoverflow chat , refer link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funkload